# Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory.. while installing twilio manually

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, twilio

I am trying to install twilio using anaconda but unfortunately anaconda does failed to install it. So i visit Twilio's site for help and in this link : https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python  I found the option for manual installation using python but I got the error stating : error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\twilio\rest\api\v2010\account\incoming_phone_number\assigned_add_on\__pycache__\assigned_add_on_extension.cpython-37.pyc.2034953229336'

I am not able to install twilio using anaconda on my PC(Windows 10 64 bit). Can anyone please help me to solve the above stated problem or to install twilio using anaconda.

I have also tried installing from : https://anaconda.org/jonrowland/twilio but the last update is 5 years old and therefore failed.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I find I can run pip commands on anaconda so i simply ran the following command in command prompt :-

pip install twilio

and twilio was successfully installed.